# How to get month value using week value hive

Tags: date, hive, hiveql, week-number

I want to get month value using week no. I have week numbers stored in a table with year value
How to query database to get month value using that week value.
I am using hiveQL.

Eample:

```
201801(week) ------->201801(month)
201804(week) ------->201801(month)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose week has full 7 days. Extract week number, multiply 7, add to 'year-01-01' and extract month from result date, lpad with 0 to get '01' from 1 and concatenate with year:

```
with data_example as(
select stack(3,'201801','201804','201805') as yr_wk
)

select yr_wk, concat(substr(yr_wk, 1,4),
                     lpad(month(date_add(date(concat(substr(yr_wk, 1,4),'-01-01')),int(substr(yr_wk, 5,2))*7)),2,0)
                    ) yr_mth
 from data_example
```

Result:

```
yr_wk   yr_mth
201801  201801
201804  201801
201805  201802
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If there are 53 weeks in year, how can I write a query?

Comment: @Spark do not know how to deal with 52/52 week years... The methiood using date_add weeks*7 to the 2018-01-01 may be not accurate... but I do not know another solution